# Trying to run PhantomJS (webdriver) as service with systemd

Tags: systemd, phantomjs

I want to run PhantomJS in webdriver mode as a service on a CentOS box.

I created this systemd file but somehow the command-line argument is not accepted. The error message is `Unit phantomjs-webdriver.service failed to load: Invalid argument.`

```
[Unit]
Description=PhantomJS Webdriver
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=xxxxx
ExecStart=phantomjs --webdriver=4444
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Is it at all possible to use command-line switches in `ExecStart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, command-line switches in `ExecStart` are allowed in unit files. For example:

```
$ grep ExecStart /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshd -D
```

Your unit is not valid because the first `ExecStart=` argument must be the a full path of an executable file ([reference](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=)). You can find it with `which phantomjs` command.